# renaming series of files using xargs

Tags: bash, shell, xargs, parameter-expansion

I would like to rename several files picked by `find` in some directory, then use `xargs` and `mv` to rename the files, with *parameter expansion*. However, it did not work...

**example**:

```
mkdir test
touch abc.txt
touch def.txt

find . -type f -print0 | \
xargs -I {} -n 1 -0 mv {} "${{}/.txt/.tx}"
```

**Result**:

```
bad substitution
[1]    134 broken pipe  find . -type f -print0
```

**Working Solution**:

```
for i in ./*.txt ; do mv "$i" "${i/.txt/.tx}" ; done
```

Although I finally got a way to fix the problem, I still want to know why the first `find` + `xargs` way doesn't work, since I don't think the second way is very general for similar tasks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that shell variable substitution happens **before** your command runs.  So when you run:

```
find . -type f -print0 | \
xargs -I {} -n 1 -0 mv {} "${{}/.txt/.tx}"
```

The shell tries to expan that `${...}` construct before `xargs` even
runs...and since that contents of that expression aren't a valid shell variable reference, you get an error.  A better solution would be to use the `rename` command:

```
find . -type f -print0 | \
xargs -I {} -0 rename .txt .tx {}
```

And since `rename` can operate on multiple files, you can simplify
that to:

```
find . -type f -print0 | \
xargs -0 rename .txt .tx
```

Comment: 'shell variable substitution happens before your command runs', that's a golden word, thx a lot! I am not familiar with `rename`, so it leads to another question: if I want to substitute some middle part of file name, not only prefix or suffix, how could I do that with `rename`?

Comment: Rename actually operates on the entire filename, so for example `rename foo bar *` would rename `this_foo_example` to `this_bar_example`. Take a look through the `rename` man page and experiment a bit.  If it doesn't work the way you want, consider posting a new question.